# I want to pop up a MsgBox when counter is 3, 6, 9, 12.......99

Tags: vb.net

I want to pop up a MsgBox when counter is 3, 6, 9, 12.......99.

Following code need to be reparied.

```
    Dim Counter As Integer
    Do While Counter Is threefold
        MsgBox("Hello")
        Counter = Counter + 1
    Loop
```

Comment: You are looking for the "mod" operator (Google this :))

Comment: Thank you, solved.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

assuming 99 is your limit, using mod like below will help.

Mod gives you the ability to find divisors of a number, as the remainder is always 0. (in your case, you're after 'Mod 3')

```
Dim counter As Integer = 1
While counter < 100
   If (counter mod 3) = 0 Then
      MsgBox("Hello")
   End If
   Counter += 1
End While
```

Fiddle here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gvFjGV

An alternative way to do it is with a For loop - this will save the need of declaring counter & remembering to increment within the loop

Comment: This does not work. It shows Hello `if Counter = 0` and in the question it starts at 3

Comment: Quite right. Changing the initial counter value to 1 prevents this (if indeed undesired).

Comment: Let's hope that his counter does not start at 0 :) @Greaterix

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Mod Operator.

I don't know what is **threefold**, but you can test this loop :

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 99
    If i > 0 Then
        If i Mod 3 = 0 Then
            MsgBox(i)
        End If
    End if
Next
```

**EDIT :** As Rubens mentioned, this is possible too :

```
For i As Integer = 3 To 99 Step 3
    If i Mod 3 = 0 Then
        MsgBox(i)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you. Solved.

Comment: You could start with 3 and use the [`Step`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx) option